# how to set clickonce application install offline use?

Tags: c#, clickonce

i want to make my clickonce application install as offline from local path by clicking the .application file like this

[image]

.Is work on my development machine.

However when i  zip my publish folder to end user,and user click the .application file. it keep promt user install from server url. like this

[image]

Can anyone help me out?I want let end user install with local path.

Answer (score 0):

click on your project->properties->publish
in section of  publishing folder location, check if you set it to server url, change it to local address. so zip your publish folder and try again to install it in your client systems.